# Are there any Objective-C frameworks like Cocoa which provide Arrays, Dictionaries, Strings, etc

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, dictionary

Before I start to write my own, are there any Objective-C frameworks or libraries that provide Arrays, Dictionaies and Strings? I am writing for windows so there is no Cocoa, there are ports. But I am only writing a small command line application so I don't really want to use Cocoa because it is quite large. I have looked around and all I can find is Cocoa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation framework provides standard containers for you (each of them can hold objective-c objects only):

- NSArray and NSMutableArray
- NSString and NSMutableString
- NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary
- NSSet and NSMutableSet

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise Foundation was separate to Cocoa.

Comment: I would say Cocoa consists of Foundation (the data types) and AppKit (the UI objects) ... I'm just trying to be pedantic :p

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html

(Possibly)